# Issue with indexing repositories using gradle in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, artifactory

Every time I restart Intellij I get the error below. Any suggestion on how to resolve it?

> **Unindexed remote maven repositories found.**
>   The following repositories
>   used in your gradle projects were not indexed yet:
>   https://mycompany.artifactoryonline.com/mycompany/libs-releases
>   If you want to use dependency completion for these repositories
>   artifacts, Open Repositories List, select required repositories and
>   press "Update" button

The url that is mentioned in the error message is set in the `.gradle` file. The project was a Maven project that is now converted to gradle.

**Intellij version**: 14.1.5

**Gradle version**: 2.7

Comment: Have you tried to update this repo, as it's said in this notification? If it doesn't help, you can simply disable this notification.

Comment: I have tried to update repo and disable the notification. When i restart intellij the message returns. If I'm able to prevent this then it would be preferable.

Comment: It was an issue in older version of IDE (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134203), but it was fixed in 14.0.3. Don't you become some notification messages while updating the repo? I have a 14.1.3 version installed and have a local repo, which can't be indexed, I just turned off the notification "Unindexed maven repositories gradle detection" at Settings - Appearance & Behaviour - Notifications